# Unit testing monaco editor renders only first line

Tags: unit-testing, monaco-editor, jsdom

I am using vite+vitest for my project. I installed `vitest-canvas-mock` and its successful in running the tests.
But it is rendering only the first line in the code. I am not able to add text or see any other features.

Did anyone figure out how to write proper unit tests involving monaco-editor.

We are heavily invested in monaco-editor and it would be good to be able to write unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Monaco-editor only renders as much as is needed to fill the available space. Make sure you have enough vertical space in your mock DOM to render more lines.

Comment: Sounds promising, I will give it a try and get back to you. Thankyou !